# Wrong commit message being displayed in CircleCI

Tags: git, bitbucket, circleci

We are having some issues with CircleCI showing the wrong commit message (and sometimes skips the build). It is the issue as this: https://discuss.circleci.com/t/wrong-git-commit-message-being-displayed/25346, but the author didn't follow up..

Anyhow, I can try to explain.. After every release, we bump the version of the program a commit message containing [ci skip]. This works like a charm, but the build screen always show the wrong git message.

**Example**: we see the following Git commit message when looking at the list of builds:
[image]
Take note of the latest commit-hash: **41b4245** (latest commit), but the message "refactor ThreadUtil ..." is **not** the commit message for that hash, it should be "**a change in the consent client**". 
[image]

I have tested with many repos and it seems like CircleCI (or the webhook from Bitbucket) uses the last commit from a `git log -n 5` to display the message & decide whether or not to build. 
Here is the git-commands I have used to replicate this issue:

[image]

---

If the last 5 commits (latest with `git log -n 5`) contains a [ci skip] the build gets skipped and we have to add a commit to force-build.
[image]
Take note of the hash **314e2fc**. The displayed message is from another commit (hash: **fe6638a**). 
[image]

**BUT** if I make a new commit after this it works.. and displays correctly
[image]
This always happens when we are creating a new branch.

**Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong when I'm branching out in git?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the CircleCI support. They are investigating this issue now, but they coudn't give me an ETA. I will edit my answer when the issue is fixed.

Edit: The issue was marked as solved today. 24. April 2019